# Is there any way to keep html tags when using GetElementsByTagName?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following code:

```
$url = file_get_contents('url');
$webpage = new DOMDocument();
$webpage->loadHTML($url);
$tables = $webpage->getElementsByTagName('table');
echo $tables->item(3)->nodeValue;
```

When I echo the third table that the method has got from the webpage, I can see there aren't html tags, but I need them because `<tr>` tags have information that I'm treating after getting the elements.

I have been searching for solutions, maybe some property of NodeList class, from php.net but I've got nothing.

Comment: Attempted solutions? HTML markup?

Comment: nvm, I get it. You're using `nodeValue` like an `innerHTML` call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get tables from HTML code using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510793/get-tables-from-html-code-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that you can use to get a node's html content:

```
function innerHTML(DOMNode $node)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
    }

    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DOMNode DOMNodelist::item ( int $index )` requires the index as parameter. Index starts with 0. So the third one should be index 2.

You can get the content recursively for example with this [PHP Manual User Note](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89718).

Comment: Sorry, It was the fourth table, index 3.